# AWS Lambda - import csv files based on the file name

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I have a model that I am trying to move on to AWS Lambda. I came across some items I can not find the answer to. I need to import several csv files based on the name and then combine them. In python, I was using a simple glob function that does not work in lambda. My guidance will be much appreciated.

I have this code in Python

```
inputFiles = glob.glob('C:/Users/some files/test*.csv')

df_list = []
for filename in sorted(inputFiles):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
    Final_df= pd.concat(df_list)
```

and I tried to use similar code to do the same with nil luck (it produced an empty set)

```
inputFiles = glob.glob('s3://my-bucket/test*.csv')

df_list = []
for filename in sorted(inputFiles):
    df_list.append(pd.read_csv(filename))
    Final_df= pd.concat(df_list)
```

**update** I have the loop to read all the required names but cannot find the way to import them as data frames?

```
bucket=s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    if key.key.startswith('test'):
        print(key.key)
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob` will not work with s3 URIs, it's not a normal filesystem. `boto3` is the Python SDK for AWS, you can use it to list the objects in a bucket and retrieve them. You can then read the local copies with pandas. Check out the api documentation for these methods:

- [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2)
- [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object)
- [download_file](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.download_file)

Comment: Thanks for that. I have a loop now to read required files `bucket=s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    if key.key.startswith('test'):
        print(key.key)` buy cannot find a way to import them as data frames?

Comment: @Kalenji you can use the `download_file` method I linked above to download the objects to a local file, then load that file from the local path.

Comment: but I need to move the script from the local machine to AWS. Any idea or links how to use AWS Lambda (S3) temp folder. Files are small.

Comment: @Kalenji sorry for not being clear, when I say "local file" I mean locally to the lambda execution environment. AWS lambdas give you a `/tmp` directory that you can use for file storage. You'd do something like `download_file('{bucket}', '{key}', '/tmp/{key}')`.

Comment: I have this code to ready my bucket but now I have the issue that all files are read seperately. `bucket = s3_resource.Bucket(bucket_name)
for obj in bucket.objects.all():
    x = obj.get()['Body'].read().decode()
    #print(obj.key)
    print(x)` any idea how to move it to create just one data frame out of them?